# How to handle Oracle information in Python?

Tags: python, database, oracle

I'm trying to extract information from Oracle to Python lists in order to use them as inputs in functions. I am using the following code:

```
import cx_Oracle 
dsnRiesgos = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host="MYHOST", port ="MYPORT", sid="MYSID")
conect = cx_Oracle.connect(user="USER",password="PASS",dsn=dsnRiesgos)
cursor = conect.cursor()
query = """ MY_QUERY """
Referencias = []
Referencias_Exp = []
cursor.execute(query) 
#The result is a view with five columns and 400,000+ rows 
for row in cursor:
    Referencias.append(row[1])
    Referencias_Exp.append([row[1],row[4]])
```

The problem that I have is that the output from 'query' is 400,000+ rows and it is taking forever to complete the insertion in the lists (I have stopped it after 15 minutes). My intuition tells me that there is a more efficient way to do this but I don't know how.

I am using Windows 7, Python 3.6.2, Oracle client: instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.

I am beginner with Python and it's the first time I connect it with Oracle so 'basic' concepts might be unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only seem to need the first and fourth columns, I would advise that you create a query that only gets those.

Then, using fetchall() (http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html) might be of assistance to you. It will bring you a list of tuples, each tuple being one of the rows yielded by your query.

And to move from the 'how' to the 'why': why do you need all 400k rows in a list before processing it? Can't you avoid this step? Minor optimizations aside, this will be inherently slow and would be best avoided.